# How can I connect to a Juniper Junos Pulse VPN from a Windows 10 PC?

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-10, juniper

Just upgraded to Windows 10. I used to be able to configure Juniper VPN connection on Windows 8.1 natively without any additional software. "Juniper Networks Junos Pulse" was listed in [Windows 8.1's VPN configuration screen](https://it.vanderbilt.edu/security/secure-communications/remote-access/junos-pulse-faq.php#win81).

In Windows 10, it is no longer an option.

Is this a problem with my installation? Or does it require additional software now?

Comment: You should install Junos Pulse VPN from [The Windows 10 Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/junos-pulse-vpn/9wzdncrdfm0n).

Comment: That appears to only work for Mobile devices. It doesn't appear in the Desktop Windows 10 store.

Comment: It's best to find an installation file on the [Support website](https://www.juniper.net/support/downloads/?p=pulse). If you can't for some reason, one download I managed to find from [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_security/junos-pulse-stuck-on-securring-connection-after/40f4ef95-6e52-425b-a1e1-ec65181529ab?page=5) is [found here](http://1drv.ms/1SYvDrL) (I don't take responsibility, but it's reported on August 10 as working).

Comment: Do you have any feedback ?

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same problem a time ago when our VPN was still on Juniper hardware. We no longer work with Juniper currently (not for this reason, though).

As per the [Juniper Knowledge center](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB29856&cat=&actp=LIST):

> Will Pulse Secure add Windows 10 to its list of supported client list?
>   Yes. Pulse Secure is qualifying Windows 10 using the Windows 10
>   Technical Preview builds. This qualification process will be an
>   ongoing exercise until the final Windows 10 builds are released by
>   Microsoft on July 29, 2015.

I don't know if this actually happened at this date, since we no longer user Windows 10 at this time either.

Comment: Unfortunately, that client is only for Windows 10 Mobile. Thanks though.

Comment: You're right, sorry, I removed that part.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the application client if you go to the website and use the SSL client that the website provides, it works under Windows 10. You need to right click and run the browser as administrator however so the software can install or update each time.